# Solve multiple tabs Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app in which I have an `activationView`. After the app is activated, I need to show rest of the views in Tabs. I have googled and found that to use Tabs in iPhone the application must be a `Tab Bar Application` which my application isn't as per my requirement. What is the best way to implement tabs(on second View in app) ?

**EDIT 1**

Codes I have tried

```
/*  tabsController = [[Tabs alloc] init];
        [self.window setRootViewController:tabsController];*/

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabsController;
```

I have tried the these ways but I am getting a plain white View.

Comment: hi you can follow my answer...and if you need any help then free to contact.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460013/remove-uitabbar-controller/12460244#12460244

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018652/adding-uitabbarcontroller-to-a-uiviewcontroller/12019226#12019226

Answer (score 2):

Try below the code when you will move from first view to your tab bar view.

> AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication
>   sharedApplication]delegate];  appDelegate.window.rootViewController =
>   yourTabbarController;

Comment: I am getting a plain white view

Comment: I have added nothing there via code, only via xib file. Is that where I am going wrong ?

Comment: does it's(tabsController) outlet connected to xib?

Comment: yeah it is connected with the item1

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for multiple VC in a single project. So declare and initialise  a VC for loginVC and otherVCs(for tabbar) in appDelegate and after login successful call the following function.

On launch make LoginVC as RootViewController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{// declare LoginVC and make it rootViewController
 self.window.rootViewController = self._loginVCObj;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

`#pragma mark- Continue to next screen after successful Login`

```
-(void) continueToNextView
{   // Handle UI after Login like.
 [_loginVCObj._indicator stopAnimating];
    [_loginVCObj._loginButton setEnabled:YES];
//add the VC to the tabbar 
    self._tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationControllerList,_favItemListNavObj, _toDoHereVC, _settingNavObj, nil]; 
// make tabbar as rootViewController
     self.window.rootViewController = self._tabBarController;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code works in the "window-based application", but with the new SDK, you cannot new a project like this.

if you wanna use your code, this will help you: 
[Cannot find window-based application on XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005546/cannot-find-window-based-application-on-xcode)

if you use storyboard, it's quite easy to build such a app.